# python - Remove every using start and end charactord

Tags: python, string, split

I may be simple, with regex, im not able to remove some characters using start and end charactors.

```
string = 'this is my test (20)'
```

Basically I want to print before the open bracket.

```
this is my test
```

I tried with split

```
string = '('.join(split[:0]))
```

Not sure about correct syntax,.

Comment: `print(string.split('(')[0])` ?

Comment: Oh yes, this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split` and `strip` to remove extra spaces at the end of the string

`print(string.split("(")[0].strip())`